# Root-like directories

Tags: permissions, root, multiple-users

Forgive me if I understand the Linux file system wrong here.

Can I add different root-*like* directories for users?

Example; I want to `sudo apt install ncar-ncl` in a user named **climate**, so when I remove the user climate one day it'll remove everything I installed in that specific user eg. ncar-ncl.

The reason; I mess my computer all time, still relatively new to Linux. In my mind if I do this I can safely remove the **climate** user with all that was in it and keep the **admin** user to revert back to instead of reinstalling.

Comment: The easier way would be to make a backup or to use virtual machines.